# t-sql select count(*) to integer variable creates exception for can't be varchar type can't be converted to int?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, count

I am not new to SQL technologies and have some experience with PL/SQL but T-SQL is really working way different than PL/SQL... I am building a database trigger that i am trying to calculate/sum two types of values and check how many times that they do exist in my table, then will simply implement a business logic over this calculation. All type declarations are done at the beginning:

```
USE [DB_KD_Benchmarking_SQL]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[InsertTrigger_int_ext_mix_2]    Script Date: 12/2/2020 3:36:51 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[InsertTrigger_int_ext_mix_2] ON [dbo].[Ext_trial_2]
    AFTER INSERT 
    AS DECLARE @Order_id_var_2 varchar(255),
               @Country_var_2 varchar(50),
               @Panel_brand_var_2 varchar(255),
               @Int_ext_mix_var_2 char(10),
               @Business_field_var_2 char(10),
               @RC_Code_var_2 char(10),
               @FC_Code_var_2 char(10),
               @F_ident_number_var_2 varchar(255),
               @Repeated_repairs_var_2 varchar(255),
               @Same_order_ID_int int,
               @Same_order_ID_ext int,
               @Total_Same_order_ID int,
               @Total_Same_order_ID_integer int;

    DECLARE new_order CURSOR FOR
    SELECT Country, Order_id, Panel_Brand, Internal_Ext_Mix, Business_Field, RC_Code, FC_Code, F_ident_Number, Repeated_Repairs FROM inserted     
    OPEN new_order;
    FETCH NEXT FROM new_order INTO @Country_var_2, @Order_id_var_2, @Panel_brand_var_2,  @Int_ext_mix_var_2, @Business_field_var_2, @RC_Code_var_2, @FC_Code_var_2, @F_ident_number_var_2, @Repeated_repairs_var_2;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
    BEGIN
    
    select @Same_order_ID_int = count(*) from Ext_trial_2 where Order_id = @Order_id_var_2 and Internal_Ext_Mix = 'Int';
    Print '@Same_order_ID_int ' + @Same_order_ID_int; 

    select @Same_order_ID_ext = count(*) from Ext_trial_2 where Order_id = @Order_id_var_2 and Internal_Ext_Mix = 'Ext';
    Print '@Same_order_ID_ext ' + @Same_order_ID_ext; 

    set @Total_Same_order_ID = @Same_order_ID_int + @Same_order_ID_ext;
    Print '@Total_Same_order_ID ' + @Total_Same_order_ID ; 
        IF @Total_Same_order_ID > 1 and (@Int_ext_mix_var_2 = 'Int' or @Int_ext_mix_var_2 = 'Ext')
          BEGIN
            Insert into Ext_trial_2 (Country, Order_id, Panel_Brand, Internal_Ext_Mix, Business_Field, RC_Code, FC_Code, F_ident_Number, Repeated_Repairs) 
                Values (@Country_var_2, @Order_id_var_2, @Panel_brand_var_2, 'Mix', @Business_field_var_2, @RC_Code_var_2, @FC_Code_var_2, @F_ident_number_var_2, @Repeated_repairs_var_2);
            Delete from Ext_trial_2 where  Order_id = @Order_id_var_2 and Internal_Ext_Mix = 'Int';
          END  
    FETCH NEXT FROM new_order INTO  @Country_var_2, @Order_id_var_2, @Panel_brand_var_2,  @Int_ext_mix_var_2, @Business_field_var_2, @RC_Code_var_2, @FC_Code_var_2, @F_ident_number_var_2, @Repeated_repairs_var_2;
    END
    CLOSE new_order
    DEALLOCATE new_order
```

As you might see that @Same_order_ID_int & @Same_order_ID_ext & @Total_Same_order_ID is defined as type int. Here i try to assign values to them :

```
select @Same_order_ID_int = count(*) from Ext_trial_2 where Order_id = @Order_id_var_2 and Internal_Ext_Mix = 'Int';
    Print '@Same_order_ID_int ' + @Same_order_ID_int; 

    select @Same_order_ID_ext = count(*) from Ext_trial_2 where Order_id = @Order_id_var_2 and Internal_Ext_Mix = 'Ext';
    Print '@Same_order_ID_ext ' + @Same_order_ID_ext; 

    set @Total_Same_order_ID = @Same_order_ID_int + @Same_order_ID_ext;
    Print '@Total_Same_order_ID ' + @Total_Same_order_ID ;
```

This part of the trigger always fires an exception and creates an error and fires exception why i try to insert row for table which I have defined :

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to datatype int for variable @Same_order_ID_int. When i change type of Same_order_ID_int to varchar(255), it works fine and return some results and assign to variable with string '1' or '0'.

Then this leads to an error on calculation method to sum these variables :

```
set @Total_Same_order_ID = @Same_order_ID_int + @Same_order_ID_ext;
```

returns string "10" or "01" or "11" which is definitely not a proper integer values. Can someone please explain me where could be problem on my calculation ?

I am using SQL Server 2016 build version 13.0.5.

Thanks for your answers in advance.

Comment: All those `DECLARE`s have a code smell to them and that you are assuming a `TRIGGER` occurs once per row (or worse an `INSERT` can only `INSERT` 1 row at a time). That isn't how triggers or `INSERT` statements work,

Comment: Let me reformat this question by adding all of trigger code here.

Comment: Well, you're not assuming there's a single row in there, but a `CURSOR` in a `TRIGGER` is going to be *awful* for performance. You really need to use set-based solutions in a `TRIGGER`, a large `INSERT` on the table would be *very* slow and costly with such a `TRIGGER`.

Comment: Thanks for the reccomendation... Here the topic is, i am trying to run cursor over "inserted" table which i assume only contains rows of AFTER INSERT statement. Regarding to business logic & requirement i have to implement it like this. Any other performant solution is totally welcome and i can approve that it is running slow with migration data that i am inserting with.

Comment: Why do you want to cursor in a `TRIGGER` at all? If you **must** `CURSOR` don't do it in the `TRIGGER`, put the data else where and then process that data in a `CURSOR` on a scheduled task. (Though I still doubt a `CURSOR` is needed.)

Comment: CURSOR is there to cover requirement that people are using to fill in this table with excel file... Otherwise on normal inserts over API or normal SQL statements, it certainly works without cursor definition. But when people are tring to import BULK data without insert statements(no SQL knowledge for them) they are referring to Excel import....

Comment: Then, like I said, if you "must" use a `CURSOR`, then do it outside the `TRIGGER`.

Comment: Understood, will declare it outside of trigger definition. Thanks for this hint as well!

Comment: Larnu, one more topic to understand, what did you mean by "using curser outside TRIGGER" ? I should define this cursor as a database object or i need to write cursor definition in trigger, before "alter trigger" statement ? (which i have tried and it did not work.). Thanks for your comment in advance.

Comment: See my prior [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65110693/t-sql-select-count-to-integer-variable-creates-exception-for-cant-be-varchar?noredirect=1#comment115110934_65110693)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem

```
declare @Same_order_ID_int int = 2

Print '@Same_order_ID_int ' + @Same_order_ID_int;
```

fails with

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '@Same_order_ID_int ' to data type int.
```

Because you're trying to use the '+' operator with a varchar and an int.  Instead use [CONCAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) which handles string conversion and null-to-empty string conversion for you.

```
Print concat('@Same_order_ID_int ', @Same_order_ID_int);
```

Comment: Blind people ask questions... :) Thanks for your kindness, will try and approve answer here. Sorry for being blind & rookie and thanks for your kind time that you read & answer my question.